# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

`a.taxamount` is between `0.0` and `20.0`, and I would like to display it as `0.0%` or `120.0%` but I am getting a conversion error.

```sql
SELECT....
,(a.taxamount * 100) + '%' AS TaxAmount
```

Comment: Use concat: `SELECT CONCAT(a.taxamount * 100, '%')`

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 - CONCAT is not a recognised function :(

Answer (score 4):

The `+` operator is used both for addition and concatenation. If you mix strings and numbers addition is assumed and it tries to implicitly cast the string to a number.

As you are on SQL Server 2008 you should convert the number to `varchar` first before concatenating.

```
CAST(a.taxamount * 100 AS VARCHAR(10)) + '%'
```

On more recent versions you could use the `CONCAT` function that does this implicitly or use `FORMAT(a.taxamount, 'P1')` to multiply by 100 and append the percent character.

Comment: faster than me :-)

Comment: Thanks! Probably worth knowing that I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 which doesn't support these. How would this look when converting to varchar? Still getting conversion issues.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks so much! I had declared the a.taxamount values as strings hence why I couldn't get it first time!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query.

```
SELECT CAST((a.taxamount * 100) AS VARCHAR(10))+ '%' AS TaxAmount
```